# Importing an Image from an XML File

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I'm trying to produce a system which takes an image in OpenCV, writes it to XML, reads it from XML, and displays it in an Image control in a WPF application.

The problem I'm having is that I'm unclear as to how .NET classes (e.g. BitmapImage) process images from a byte array. I've tried a number of methods and gotten various errors - too numerous to post unless required.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction regarding this? What I want to know is how does the data need to be presented to a .NET object in order to display it in an Image control?

Thanks in advance for your help - it is much appreciated.

EDIT: I expect what I need to do is convert the XML into a byte array and use that, along with a definition of the format, to instantiate a BitmapImage object or equivalent to use as source for the Image control. What I'm not sure of is how to do this.

Comment: You can't just expect an Image class in any language to render byte streams as an image. The binary data must represent the binary data of an image first. You have 2 options: parse the XML yourself, and render it into a Bitmap, or, have a control that knows how to parse the XML load it then render the DC of that control into a Bitmap.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'm sorry, I don't follow. The XML data does represent an image - it's pixel-by-pixel RGB values. What I want to know is how to turn that (parsed) data into an image.

Comment: y dont you save the image in `Base64` instead of those `pixels`.And if **OpenCV** doesn't support then u wud have to manually retrieve those pixels and store it in `Bitmap` using `SetPixel` or using `pointers` for fast processing

Comment: Can you show an example of your XML in your original post?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead The XML itself is unimportant - I can change that as needed. What I want to know is what .NET classes I should use and how they want the data to be presented - I can present it however they need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was (presumably) that I wasn't Base64 encoding the XML data before writing it. Thus the solution is to Base64 encode the data before writing to XML, Base64 decoding it on the other side, reading the data as a byte array and using that to instantiate a MemoryStream and then a BitmapImage object.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Use `int cvSaveImage(const char* filename, const CvArr* image)`
to [save](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) the file as an Image.The image format is chosen based on the filename extension

No need to store it in `XML` if you can directly store it as Image file.

The .NET classes requires an Image.That's it.

Note:

If you want to store red,green,blue values as comma separated strings, it would be very **inefficient**.Save it in `Base64` instead.You can then convert it into bytes and feed it to any .NET image class.Also the .NET `ImageConverter` Class may be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
public static BitmapSource Create(
    int pixelWidth,
    int pixelHeight,
    double dpiX,
    double dpiY,
    PixelFormat pixelFormat,
    BitmapPalette palette,
    Array pixels,
    int stride
)
```